# Expandable List Indicator

Tags: android

I have an expandable list

so two question

1. (I've seen somme similar question
   but never found the answer) How do I
   hide the arrow ( group indicator)
   when there's no children

   I tried to do it in the adapter

   ```
   public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
   if(getChildrenCount(groupPosition)==0) {
         // how do i hide the group indicator ?
   }
   ```

   But I'm stuck So, how can modify the
   group indicator for empty groups ?
2. How to have different behavior when
   you click on the arrow (expands the
   group) vs you click on the title of
   the group (go to an activity)

Comment: Did u ever figure out your answers especially question 2?thx

Answer (score 4):

1. You have to set a [GroupIndicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setGroupIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) drawable with different states. Check out [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html), maybe for the "state_empty" specify a null drawable.

Comment: i used this <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/down" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/down" />
</selector>..but everthing goes transparent---the one has chlid also

Answer (score 2):

Just create a group_indicator.xml file in drawable folder to specify the parent state using the code,

```
<item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
<item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrowright"></item>
```

Then specify this style in the Expandable list view using the code,

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ExpandableListView>
```