# Android ExpandableListView - handling parents with no children

Tags: android, android-widget, expandablelistview

I have a ragged hierarchy of parents and children.
Some parents have 5 children, while others have 0 children.

The expandableListView displays the "Expand/Collapse" icon even if there are no children.

Is there a way to hide the icon for only those Parents (rows) that have no children?
I still want to show the row of the Parents with no children, and allow a user to click on them, but the "Expand/Collapse" icon is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Another site suggests that you can set a drawable with state "empty" for the Child Indicator.

Have a look here: [Expandable List Indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189390)

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setGroupIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Comment: This example seems to change all the Parent rows...not just the a single group row.

Answer (score 0):

I used a small trick, making a group indicator transparent:

```
android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
```

The description is in this site:

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/06/hiding-group-indicator-for-empty-groups.html